# I have a file that has 40 lines. How do I append the string xyz1 to the 1st, 9th, 17th, 25th and 33rd lines in the file, and so on?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file "servers" that has 40 lines.  The file looks like this:

- "server1" lines 1 to 8
- "server2" lines 9 to 16
- "server3" lines 17 to 24
- "server4" lines 25 to 32
- "server5" lines 33 to 40

I need to append:

- the string xyz1 to the 1st, 9th, 17th, 25th and 33rd line in the file
- the string xyz2 to the 2nd, 10th, 18th, 26th and 34th line
- the string pqr1 to the 3rd, 11th, 19th, 27th and 35th line
- the string pqr2 to the 4th, 12th, 20th, 28th and 36th line
- the string pqr3 to the 5th, 13th, 21st, 29th and 37th line
- the string pqr4 to the 6th, 14th, 22nd, 30th and 38th line
- the string pqr5 to the 7th, 15th, 23rd, 31st and 39th line
- the string pqr6 to the 8th, 16th, 24th, 32nd and 40th line in the file.

How do I achieve the above in Linux ?  Please let me know.

Comment: this looks like homework, what tools were you told to use ? awk ? ed ?

Comment: On linux, you probably have `sed` at hand. Have a look at what `sed '1~8s/$/xyz1/' filename` does and adapt it. Read the addressing chapter of `man sed` if necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example input and the output you expect from it. Use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format both input and output as code (the `{}` button) so we can then copy it and use it to test our solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with awk using modulo operator as conditional. This is only for the first string. You can follow the same idea for the rest.

```
awk -i inplace 'NR % 8 == 1 { print $0"xyz1"; next } { print }' infile

╰─ → $ cat -n infile
     1  server1xyz1
     2  server1
     3  server1
     4  server1
     5  server1
     6  server1
     7  server1
     8  server1
     9  server2xyz1
    10  server2
    11  server2
    12  server2
    13  server2
    14  server2
    15  server2
    16  server2
    17  server3xyz1
    18  server3
    19  server3
    20  server3
    21  server3
    22  server3
    23  server3
    24  server3
    25  server4xyz1
    26  server4
    27  server4
    28  server4
    29  server4
    30  server4
    31  server4
    32  server4
    33  server5xyz1
    34  server5
    35  server5
    36  server5
    37  server5
    38  server5
    39  server5
    40  server5
```

You can add the flag `-v inplace::suffix=.bak` to create a backup file or remove `-i inplace` just to see the printed output.

Comment: Superb!!!! This worked.  Thank you.